# How can i create StateClient or Connector Client Objects in Other Controllers except Message Controller?

Tags: botframework

I am working on bot framework technology, in one of my project I want to update these below lines of code from version 1 to version 3 bot framework.

```
 var client = new ConnectorClient();
            var getData = await client.Bots.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.botId, userid);
            getData.Data = ar.Serialize();
            var foo = await client.Bots.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.botId, userid, getData);
```

Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
{
 // Get any saved values
 StateClient sc = activity.GetStateClient();
 BotData userData = sc.BotState.GetPrivateConversationData(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id);

 boolAskedForUserName = userData.GetProperty<bool>("AskedForUserName");
 strUserName = userData.GetProperty<string>("UserName") ?? "[No User Name]";

 // Set BotUserData
userData.SetProperty<string>("UserName", strUserName);

 // Save BotUserData
    sc.BotState.SetPrivateConversationData(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id, userData);
}
```

See:
[Creating a Hello World! Bot Using The Microsoft Bot Framework](http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/6/Creating-a-Hello-World-Bot-Using-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework)

Comment: you have to wrote the above code in MessagesController but I want the same code in other controller for example LoginController. In MessagesController its working fine because it having activity reference but when I am trying to create the stateclient object in LoginController always activity will be Null.

Comment: To create a proper instance of StateClient you require either **MicrosoftAppCredentials** or the **Service Url**. So you do not need the Activity per se.  
    `var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri(serviceUrl));`  
Finally to access the User Data you need to have a the userId and the corresponding channelId. Looks like version 1 did not differenciate between channels when looking for a user.  
    `var data = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(channelid, userid);`

Comment: how to create the StateClient object by using MicrosoftAppCredentials and also tell me what is the serviceUrl.

Comment: First i must admid: I ran into troubles deserializing the user data using the stateClient created that way. It should be possible to overcome that issue but right now I don't know how to. 

MicrosoftAppCredentials can be instantiated using your microsoft appId and password [https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/db/d61/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_microsoft_app_credentials.html]

The serviceUrl must be stored somewhere. You can access it from any Activity within the conversation.

Comment: I used the serviceUrl  as var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9000/")); it's working in my local machine but I don't know what about after published my bot it into dev.botframework.com and added skype channel to it.

Comment: Tell me what is the serviceUrl of skype channel.

Comment: This tutorial may help: http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/12/Using-Images-Cards-Carousels-and-Buttons-In-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework in it I record the MessagesController class and then in the Dialog class get the value by simply using: context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>(

        "CurrentBaseURL", out strBaseURL);